# System.Web.Mvc vs. System.Web.WebPages.Html for SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-webpages

I noticed today that both namespaces `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web.WebPages.Html` have a SelectListItem. What is the difference between the too and is there times you should use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Web.Mvc` is specific to the MVC framework.

`System.Web.WebPages.Html` is for use with Web Pages that use Razor.

To be honest I've never used them in Web Pages but the examples I have seen they look identical, I just remember to never select the WebPages namespace.

There is an example available here:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/184/HTML-Helpers-For-Forms-In-Razor-Web-Pages

Comment: So in the controller for my MVC web app (using Razor on the views) which one should I go with?

Comment: Always go with the System.Web.Mvc. :)

Comment: Actually, both classes are identical according to the Microsoft docs here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc(v=vs.99).aspx I'd still use the mvc namespace though for the above reasons.